# How to redirect localhost:7001 to locahost:7001/myApp in weblogic

Tags: url, redirect, path, weblogic

I want to redirect the url localhost:7001 to localhost:7001/myApp in weblogic settings. Not in the web.xml of the application?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can deloy a web app on the / context root and redirect all requests to /myApp.
Another way is to use an http server in front of WebLogic to redirect request from / to /myApp